# Encrypt UDP packets

Tags: c#, c, sockets, encryption, udp

For a project, I use UDP packets to send and receive data. 
But now my supervisor wants me to encrypt the packets so they cannot be used when they are captured with, for example, Wireshark.  I wonder if there is a simple way to do this with built in functions in C or C#.  Otherwise, how can I make my own encryption function?

The code below is how I send the data in C# and receive it in an C program.

```
        var client = new UdpClient();
        IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 21); // endpoint where server is listening
        client.Connect(ep);

        string text = textBox1.Text;
        char[] arr= text.ToCharArray(0,text.Length);
        // send data
        var arr2 = new byte[100];
        arr2[0] = 0x32;
        arr2[1] = 0x40;
        arr2[2] = (byte)(text.Length);
        if(text.Length==0)
        {
            arr2[2] = 0x00;
            arr2[3] = 0x00;
            arr2[4] = 0x01;
            client.Send(arr2, text.Length + 4);
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 3; i < text.Length + 3; i++)
            {
                arr2[i] = (byte)arr[i - 3];
            }
            client.Send(arr2, text.Length + 3);
        }
    }
```

Thanx a lot

Comment: Don't be so lazy and at least search google for "C# encrypt". There are literally hundreds of thousands of results.

Answer (score 0):

Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_cryptography_libraries for  encryption libraries that you could use.

look at [Tinc](https://www.tinc-vpn.org/) & OpenVPN for ways to implement encryption over UDP packets.